# In Soviet Russia, code writes you!

Tags: code-golf, string

### Input

Two words separated by a space. It is assumed that the first is a verb.

### Output

The "Soviet counterpoint" to the input phrase, in the form of a punchline to an "in Soviet Russia" joke.

```
"break law" --> "In Soviet Russia, law break you!"
```

Accounting for correct grammar is unimportant.

Shortest program wins!

Comment: Just to clarify, we can't take 2 inputs, one of each word? i.e. `bash russia.sh break law`?

Comment: I've closed the challenge as a duplicate, because both challenges take two space-separated words and require them to be printed in reverse order with some fixed boilerplate string around/between them.

Comment: @MartinEnder: In this case the two words *don't* have anything between them in the output though, which allowed me to take a different approach in Perl 6.

Comment: @smls That's fair, you're free to cast a reopen vote.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```
{"In Soviet Russia, {.words[1,0]} you!"}
```

```
{~[R,] «you! $_ Russia, Soviet In»}
```

It works because the `« »` "word list quote" recursively splits everything on whitespace.

---

Some other answers require the input words to be passed as two separate arguments. I think that's cheating, but for the record, it would make this solution 34 bytes long (and really boring):

```
{"In Soviet Russia, $^b $^a you!"}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 20 bytes

```
“\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»⁶³ḲṚK“æw}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AUQAu///4oCcXFXhuZnIpsaSxIrDkeG5hsK74oG2wrPhuLLhuZpL4oCcw6Z3fcK7////ImJyZWFrcyBsYXci//Vuby1jYWNoZQ)

```
“\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»⁶³ḲṚK“æw}»
“\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»                   Set output to 'In Soviet Russia,'
          ⁶                  Set output to ' ' {implicitly printing the previous
                             output}
           ³                 Set output to the input {implicitly printing the 
                             previous output}             "breaks law"
            Ḳ                Split {the input} on spaces. ['breaks', 'law']
             Ṛ               Reverse list.                ['law', 'breaks']
              K              Join with spaces.            "law breaks"
               “æw}»         Set output to ' you!' {implicitly printing the
                             previous output}
```

---

Alternatively, if there's no obligation for quotes around the input, it can be done in 19 bytes.

```
“\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»⁶⁴⁶³“æw}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYU5M6MOdM08sOzbpSNfhiQ93th3a/ahx26PGLUDy0Gag/OFl5bWHdv///z@pKDUxu/h/TmL517x83eTE5IxUAA)

Comment: This seems to be assuming that the user split the input into spaces themself? `⁴` doesn't work with the input format that the OP gave.

Comment: I kind of freestyled with *two words, separated by a space*. Added another version as well.

Comment: Huh, now our solutions are the same length but actually somewhat different in terms of algorithm. (We aren't even using quite the same string literals.) Weird to see that happen.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```python
print("In Soviet Russia,",*input().split()[::-1],"you!")
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXoqHkmacQnF@WmVqiEFRaXJyZqKOko5WZV1BaoqGpV1yQkwmko62sdA1jdZQq80sVlTT//08qSk3MVshJLAcA)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 68 bytes

```
Input Str1
inString(Str1," 
"IN SOVIET RUSSIA, "+sub(Str1,Ans+1,Str1-Ans)+" "+sub(Str1,1,Ans-1)+" YOU!
```

"Accounting for correct grammar is unimportant." I guess that means I can yell everything ;)

Comment: [Capitalization is not part of grammar](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/309321/125966). The OP said that so people didn't feel the need to add an 's' to the verb or add 'the' or something.

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 32 characters

```
* *=In Soviet Russia, $2 * you\!
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ printf 'break law' | gema '* *=In Soviet Russia, $2 * you\!'
In Soviet Russia, law break you!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
Ḳ“\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»ṭṚ“©ṠẆ»ṭK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6ZHDXNiQh/unHli2bFJR7oOT3y4s@3Q7oc71z7cOQsodWjlw50LHu6CCHn///8/qSg1MVshJ7EcAA)

More fun with Jelly's compressed strings.

```
Ḳ“\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»ṭṚ“©ṠẆ»ṭK
Ḳ                     Split {the input} on spaces
           ṭ          Add an additional input to the end:
 “\UṙȦƒĊÑṆ»             "In Soviet Russia," (compressed notation)
            Ṛ         Reverse the list
                  ṭ   Add another additional input to the end:
             “©ṠẆ»      "you!" (compressed notation)
                   K  Join on spaces {and implicitly output}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

```
(.+ )(.+)
In Soviet Russia, $2 $1you!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@hp62gCSQ0uTzzFILzyzJTSxSCSouLMxN1FFSMFFQMK/NLFf//TypKTcxWyEksBwA)

Comment: @MartinEnder Right, thanks. Not sure what I was thinking

Comment: Just for fun, if we assume there are no digits in the input, another byte can be saved by separating the swapping from adding the boilerplate: https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@@8fp5wQU67NpafN5ZmnEJxflplaohBUWlycmaijoKKmUJlfqvj/f1JRamK2Qk5iOQA

Answer (score 0):

## JAPT 29 Bytes

```
`In soviet rÔëa, {V} {U} y!`
```

input: "drink" "milk"

output: In Soviet Russia, milk drink you

explaination: {U} and {V} are the input variables.
it inserts them in the string when running the code.

First code-golf ever. hope it counts!

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=YEluIHNvdmlldCBy1OthLCB7Vn0ge1V9IHmMIWA=&input=ImRyaW5rIiAibWlsayI=)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and thanks for using my language! Unfortunately, the input has to be given as a single string, but you can fix this by replacing `{V} {U}` with `{¸w ¸}` (`¸` stands for `qS`, which splits a string on spaces and joins an array on spaces, and `w` reverses an array). Also, you can leave out the last backtick to save a byte. ([Test these changes here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=YEluIHNvdmlldCBy1OthLCB7uHcguH0geYwh&input=ImRyaW5rIG1pbGsi))

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
”InË·ž¦,”I#R„€î!)˜ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYa5n3uHuQ9uP7ju0TAfEUw561DDvUdOaw@sUNU/PObzh8N7//5OKUhOzFXISywE)

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 40 bytes

```
s/(.+ )(.+)/In Soviet Russia, \2 \1you!/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#K05NUdAtSlVQ/1@sr6GnraAJJDT1PfMUgvPLMlNLFIJKi4szE3UUYowUYgwr80sV9f@r/08qSk3MVshJLAcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 29 bytes

```
iIn Soviet Russia, <C-r>b <C-r>a you!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@5/pmacQnF@WmVqiEFRaXJyZqKNg46xbZJcEoRIVKvNLFf///59UlJqY/T8nsfy/bhkA)

Note that `<C-r>` is actually ctrl-r, or ASCII `0x12`, but since that character is unprintable, using the verbose mode to represent it is more convenient.

This is probably about as short as it can get without using compression.